# Flexdashboard - hidden navbar tab using reactive values

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I can hide a navbar page using the static value of `show_hide` but I cannot figure out how to do it with the reactive value `r_show_hide()`. I have also tried using `isolate(ifelse...)` and then `r_show_hide` (no parentheses) as well as `reactiveVal()` to no avail.

There is also an extraneous `">` that shows up. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

**Update:** 
I created an issue https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/229

````
    ---
    title: "-"
    output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(shiny)

    show_hide <- "show" # "hidden"

    r_show_hide <- reactive(ifelse(session$clientData$url_hostname == "127.0.0.1", "hidden", "show"))
    ```

    Does work {.`r show_hide`}
    =============================

    ### Should be `r show_hide`


    Doesn't work {.`r reactive(r_show_hide())`}
    ===============================

    ### Should be `r renderText(r_show_hide())`
````

Comment: Do you need to wrap reactive() around r_show_hide() when calling it after “Doesn’t work”? Have you tried to put it in a paste0 call?

Comment: Some reactive function needs to be used in order to access `r_show_hide()`. I tried `renderText()` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Would a reactiveValue work with your ifelse statement instead of the reactive?

Comment: I tried that also but may not have done it correctly. Could you try mocking up an answer?

Comment: I have not been able to come up with a solution yet.

Comment: I think this might be better suited for a Shiny App, rather than a flexdashboard. I bet there are some limitations you're bumping up against here, that might be more easily overcome with pure shiny. Check out `conditionalPanel`, that might have what you want. I tried playing around with this and was unable to come up with a helpful answer

Comment: In shiny this would not be a problem at all, you could use the interactive() function which yields TRUE when shiny is started within an interactive session and FALSE when it is run on server. In Rmarkdown however, interactive() yields FALSE when run in flexdashboard.

Comment: There are already two open issues regarding the very same Problem. [Here](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/229) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/142).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this took me a while figuring out.

The fundamental problem is that r chunks in curly brackets of the flexdashboard navbar evaluate in a non-reactive context, compared to the r chucks that build the content of each page, which are evaluated in a reactive context. For this reason you cannot use a reactive such as `r_show_hide()` to trigger the argument hidden/show of the navbar page, but you can use `r_show_hide()` in a `renderText()` function within the page.

So the actual question is, how to access a reactive value from a non-reactive context. The answer is `isolate()` and is explained [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/isolate.html).

Below I provide an example using your code.

````
---
title: "-"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)

show_hide <- "show" # "hidden"

r_show_hide <- reactive(ifelse(session$clientData$url_hostname == "127.0.0.1", "hidden", "show"))
```

Does work {.`r show_hide`}
=============================

### Should be `r show_hide`


Doesn't work {.`r isolate(r_show_hide())`}
===============================

### Should be `r renderText(r_show_hide())`
````

Comment: Thank you for digging into this, this is very helpful! I tried using an `input` object and it didn't seem to work. If I add `radioButtons("show_hide", "View page", choices = c("show", "hidden"))` and then replace the reactive logic to `r_show_hide <- reactive(input$show_hide)` it goes back to not working. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I think the problem is isolating a reactive value. Once isolated it does not get updated, that’s the whole point of isolating. So the example above works because at the start of the session the reactive is created, its value is then isolated and left unchanged. So the next challenge is to provide a workaround for updating isolated reactive values - if that is even possible.

Comment: Doh, I should have realized that. Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It seems like all input values are not existent when knitting the flexdashboard document - so I see no way to make use of user input values when defining the structure of the document. Apparently the session info on the clients url is already know when knitting, because the approach above is working. Further, I found this [example](https://somtom.github.io/post/using-dynamically-rendered-r-markdown-childs-for-reports/) where they create dynamic subpages. That's probably as dynamic as a flexdashboard can get.